# How can I check if the contents of a result set are the same in the XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xquery

I have many XMLs, which can contain a specific element, functioning as an identifier for the record. It's possible that it's missing from the file, or there is only one occurence, this is the easiest case, that I could solve already. But it's also possible that there are many of these elements, in that case I need to check if their values are the same. I attached some example XMLs with the expected output:

Input 1:

```
<root>
  <daily>
    <group>ID@12</group>
    <surrounded>rich</surrounded>
    <clothing>rod</clothing>
    <outside>-1084855717</outside>
    <section>-1103031959</section>
  </daily>
  <group>ID@13</group>
  <account>remain</account>
  <point>-1624875729</point>
  <cotton>941344054.3731294</cotton>
  <group>ID@12</group>
  <scale>almost</scale>
</root>
```

Output: **false**, because there is three occurences, but one of them is different from the other 2.

Input 2:

```
<root>
  <daily>
    <group>ID@12</group>
    <mill>spread</mill>
    <surrounded>rich</surrounded>
    <clothing>rod</clothing>
    <outside>-1084855717</outside>
    <section>-1103031959</section>
  </daily>
  <group>ID@12</group>
  <account>remain</account>
  <point>-1624875729</point>
  <cotton>941344054.3731294</cotton>
  <scale>almost</scale>
</root>
```

Output: **true**, because there are two occurences, and both are the same value.

I would have to use XPath expressions, but it could be also okay with XSLT file.

I could manage to find the relevant elements with the following expression, but I'm stuck at that point:

```
//group[starts-with(text(), 'ID@')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `//group[starts-with(text(), 'ID@')]` selects the elements I would shorten that to `//group[starts-with(., 'ID@')]` first and then use `count(distinct-values(//group[starts-with(., 'ID@')])) = 1`, for instance. That assumes XPath 2 and `distinct-values` is available, as your XQuery tag suggests.

In both XSLT or XQuery it could of course be also considered a grouping of those elements by their own value and checking that there is exactly one group.

Answer (score 0):

This may look strange, but I will explain it:

```
not(//group[starts-with(text(), 'ID@')] != //group[starts-with(text(), 'ID@')])
```

The expression selects the set of ID nodes and compares it with the *same set* of ID nodes using the `!=` operator. You might think that `$x != $x` would always return a false value, but that's not how it works, actually. See the section on [boolean expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans) in the XPath 1.0 specification:

> If both objects to be compared are node-sets, then the comparison will
> be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a
> node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the
> comparison on the string-values of the two nodes is true.

In other words, if any pair of elements from the first node-set and the second node-set satisfy the comparison operator (`!=`, in our case), then the expression returns true.

In our case, if you have a node-set `$x` and you evaluate the expression `$x != $x` it will return true if there is a member of `$x` which is not equal to *some* (other) member of `$x`.

Using the `not()` function you can then negate the result, e.g. `not($x != $x)` will return false if the members of $x are not all equal to each other.

Comment: It's a neat idea, but don't use it if you have thousands of nodes: it's going to have O(n^2) performance unless the optimizer is very smart.